# Charging and discharging a Leyden Jar?

Tags: capacitor, grounding, esd, discharge

A [Leyden Jar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyden_jar) was one of the first capacitors ever. [This guy re-builds one](https://youtu.be/ZYH9dGl4gUE?t=3m23s).

He connects the outer connector to ground. That, i can understand.
I can also understand tribocharging by rubbing the (insulative) PVC pipe.

But why is he connecting the PVC to ground?!

Comment: PVC is a very good insulator, so it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Clipped to PVC, because it hurts too much when clipped to your skin.  (Heh, you're supposed to keep touching the ground when rubbing the tube, so the positive cloth becomes the generator's second terminal, via your hand.)  Original: http://www.sparkbangbuzz.com/els/stat-gen-el.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smoke-and mirrors.  The ground connection to the PVC pipe is meaningless.

Poetic effect maybe?  (Another mistake in the video is that the name of the unit is farad.  The name of the person is Michael Faraday.)

Comment: Properly, one "Faraday" is ~96,500 coulombs of electric charge

Comment: @wbeaty in the SI system the correct units are farad (F) and coulomb (C) as the full names of all units are written in lower case to distinguish them from proper names.  (your system might be different :-)

Comment: 'Faradays' *is* SI units, and supposed to be capitalized.  It's a constant used chemistry, linked to the mol.  In chem, one coulomb is far too tiny for typical lab purposes.  Also, Mr. Burns pays comic-book-guy a Faraday's worth of dollars.

Comment: @Marty yes, exactly, as user183.. said.

Answer (score 0):

The original Leyden Jar was significantly different:  fill an insulating jar or bottle with wine, hold it in your hand, insert a metal rod into the wine, then use a many-KVs, grounded DC source to charge up the wine.

See the difference?   No second plate!  Instead we end up with an invisible capacitor plate: a charged handprint, with a very strong e-field between that handprint and the wine inside.  Other parts of the wine and the jar remain "uncharged."

If you kept hold on that jar (didn't take your hand away from the handprint-charge,) and then you accidentally took a drink of the wine, POW!  You'd receive a dangerous surprise: a pulsed current through your arm, face, chest.

Also, if you put the charged bottle down, but then later picked it up, but without your hand covering the "handprint,"  ...the charge would seemingly have vanished.  It's actually still there.  The "charged capacitor" is only found between the wine and the handprint on the glass.

Adding an external conductor plate will remove all this mysterious behavior.  But it also "shorts out" a piece of interesting history, and a bit of bizarre physics where capacitors can have a dielectric separating one conductor plate and one **insulating** plate, yet still remain "charged."

Comment: If you charge the jar with external conductor, remove the outside plate, short it to the inside plate nothing will happen.  The charge does not sit on the plate but remains on the jar as @wbeaty described.